# OWIN Configuration: What's the difference between CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType and DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm revisiting some code in my OwinStartup class and have this definition:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
});
```

The constant `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` seems to come from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` and has the value of `"ApplicationCookie"`.

The constant `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType` comes from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` and has the value of `"Cookies"`. It's autodocs read *The default value used [in CookieAuthenticationOptions]*...

**What impact do these two constants have on the OWIN pipeline?**

**I'm not using any of AspNet.Identity.Core anywhere else in my solution, so should I drop the dependency and use CookieAuthenticationDefaults instead?**

Comment: The `CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType` is used for the cookie name. By default that way: `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` and is used to identify the cookie used to store the authentication information.   But for the second constant I have to guess. You can use other means to authenticate and someway you have to tell OWIN what you are using for the authentication.